# What do you get when you differentiate a $e^{f(x)}$-like function

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

I need help with exponential functions. I know that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, but wolfram alpha shows a different answer to my function below. If you, for example, take the derivative of $e^{-2x}$ do you get $-2e^{-2x}$ or $e^{-2x}$?

Answer (score 10):

You have to apply the [chain rule](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/taking-derivatives/chain_rule/v/chain-rule-definition-and-example): if $f(x)$ is a differentiable function then the derivative of $e^{f(x)}$ is $f'(x)e^{f(x)}$.

Comment: This e^(-2x) is a part of question, f(x)=e^(-2x)sin(5x). I thought i can answer it using the product rule. Do i have to use both rules or just the chain rule to solve this function above?

Comment: Yes, then it would be a combination of the product *and* chain rule!

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the chain rule here. Writing $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = -2x$ we have $h(x) := f(g(x)) = e^{-2x}$, hence by the chain rule
$$ h'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x) $$
Now $f'(x) = e^x$, hence $f'(g(x)) = e^{-2x}$, and $g'(x) = -2$, this gives
$$ h'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x) = e^{-2x} \cdot (-2) = -2e^{-2x} $$